# Multiline EditText view hiding behind reyclerview items android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Hey I used **windowSoftInputMode** in my **android manifest**. It working fine in single line text in **EditText**. I want to do same thing in my multiline text in my **EditText**.

```
<activity android:name="XYZActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

**Chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.90" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextContainer"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Working in single line text**

[image]

**But it's not working in multiline text**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the bottom constraint of your recyclerview to

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputContainer"`

The position of the guideline won't change when the inputContainer changes size. It will stay at 90%.